# Which is correct, “The man was seen to draw just now.” or “The man was seen to be drawing just now.”?

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis

Which is correct, “**The man was seen to draw a picture just now.**” or “**The man was seen to be drawing a picture just now.**”?

When I asked my coworker this question, I got the answer that neither made sense. The correct one should been “**The man was seen drawing a picture just now.**”

I didn't agree with him but could not tell why.

I am totally confused about this.

Hope somebody helps.

Comment: Without context it's impossible to say.  It's even unclear whether "draw" means "choose" or "sketch".

Comment: It means "draw a picture "

Comment: Again, context is needed.

Comment: Your coworker's suggestion seems the most natural.

Comment: Using 'to' or 'to be' can suggest that there is something illicit in the action. For instance 'the suspect was seen to take a purse from a woman's handbag'. If the man in your example was suspected of espionage (either military or industrial) and was seen drawing a picture of a naval base or an experimental vehicle then 'seen to be drawing' would be entirely appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

Like other posters, I agree that your coworker's suggestion, "was seen drawing," is correct.

While I don't know specific technical terms or rule-based generalizations that explain the correctness of this, I do know that using "was seen to be drawing" would be incorrect essentially because **it means something that doesn't make sense**.

This entry from [Macmillan Dictionary's website](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/be-seen-to-be-doing-something) describes it best:

> be seen to be doing something: to do something in a way that people will notice, because they want or expect you to do it
>
> *It’s important that we are seen to be doing something about bullying.*

In other words, "was seen to be" adds a very specific kind of meaning to a sentence. Usually it reinforces the idea that there is something dubious about the situation. For example, maybe there is doubt as to whether what is being reported actually took place. Or as in the example above, the subject ("we") wants to create a situation that has not yet happened.